# How to resolve versioning in flutter

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am want to add `url_launcher` package to `pubspec.yml` file in `flutter`.

Code for pubspec.yml

```
name: url_launch_app
description: A new Flutter application.


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  #url_launcher: '>=0.1.2 <0.2.0'
  url_launcher: '^0.4.1'
```

I have added package for url_laucher but when clicked `packages get` I am facing below error.

Error :

```
Running "flutter packages get" in url_launch_app…

The current Dart SDK version is 2.3.0-dev.0.1.flutter-cf4444b803.

Because url_launch_app depends on url_launcher >=0.1.1 <3.0.0 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to solve this versioning error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your

```
url_launcher: '^0.4.1'
```

by

```
url_launcher: ^5.0.2
```